# Pip install multiple extra dependencies of a single package via requirement file

Tags: python, pip

Some package, such as [DVC](https://dvc.org/doc/install/linux#install-with-pip) allow you to install extra dependencies to use additional features: to install a single extra dependency, whether by command line or in a `requirements.txt`, you simply use brackets:

```
# requirements.txt
dvc[s3]
```

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

But how can you install multiple extra dependencies of a single package ?
There is of course the possibility to create multiple lines

```
# requirements.txt
dvc[s3]
dvc[gs]
```

However this seems a bit unelegant to me, as if I want to specify a version,  I have to make sure that both line use the same.

Would it be possible to do that on a single line ?
I have found no reference to a specific syntax, and have already tried `dvc[s3][gs]` and `dvc[gs, s3]`, to no avail.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Of course, I found the solution right after posting, you just have to remove the space after the comma:

```
# requirements.txt
dvc[s3,gs]
```

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

works fine.