# How do I install prospector with mypy as well as bandit and other optionals

Tags: command-line, pip, python-3.6, lint, pylint

I know the example code they give is `pip install prospector[with_pyroma]` but how do I do optional extras? I've tried `pip install prospector[with_pyroma][with_mypy]` and even `pip install prospector[with_pyroma, with_mypy]`

Comment: "*I've tried…*" And what was the result? Error message?

Comment: Don't worry I figured it out, it's install prospector[with_pyroma,with_mypy] (with no spaces between)

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the space after the comma in `pip install prospector[with_pyroma,with_mypy]` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66152214/2519059